# How to test the subject of a mail with selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, automation

I want to check the subject of the mail in the inbox list that the desired mail is there or not and if it is there open that mail.

Comment: What did you already tried? Which mail service?

Comment: Ok great! What have you done so far and what mail client?

Comment: which mail have you used..??

Comment: I tried the xpath provided by firebug and able to open the first mail of the indox but how to open a mail with particular subject.i am using the outlook weburl

Comment: "//form//a/span[contains(text(),'" + linktext + "')]"; tried this also

Comment: Copy the html code of a mail.

Answer (score -1):

**/span[contains(text(),'" + linktext + "')]"**

Worked for me to get an text of a particular xpath

Comment: You.. can also use xpath of a particular inbox mail subject.